# cannot access $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: bash, path

without exporting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH anew, and without doing anything with the variable in bashrc,

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

returns

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

However,

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

returns

```
-bash: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:: No such file or dictionary
```

Yet, the path does exist.

What could've gone wrong?

------EDIT-----

```
ls -ld /usr/local{,/cuda{,/*}}
```

returns

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Apr 10 17:07 /usr/local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-7.5
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/bin
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/doc
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/extras
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/include
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/jre
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/libnsight
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/libnvvp
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/nvvm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/samples
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/share
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/src
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/tools
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   20 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CUDA, so I have removed the tag

Comment: If you just enter `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it will expand the variable, then bash will try to run it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm having a path issue while running caffe, so I thought I might look into it. Running make runtest on caffe is returning libcudart.so.6.0 not found

Comment: Does `ls -d $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` return success?

Comment: @anishsane no it returns "ls: cannot access /usr/local/cuda/lib64:: No such file or directory"

Comment: If `ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns "No such file or directory"` then the path doesn't exist (or the permissions are wrong). What does `ls -ld /usr/local{,/cuda{,/*}}` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner that actually returns a buch of directories with cuda in their path! One of them says /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-7.5, but it seems to be a link rather than directory

Comment: What does it say exactly? Update your post with the exact output. Also does the target of the list `/usr/local/cuda-7.5` exist?

Comment: @EtanReisner edited the question! Directory /usr/local/cuda-7.5 does exist.

Comment: What does `ls -ld /usr/local/cuda-7.5` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner it gives "drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Sep 16  2015 /usr/local/cuda-7.5"

Comment: And what does `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH; ls -ld "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` output?

Comment: @EtanReisner it says "ls: cannot access /usr/local/cuda/lib64:: No such file or directory"

Comment: And `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Does the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` end with a `:`? (That would explain the `ls` error and make that a false-trail and leave me uncertain what the actual issue here was to begin with other than a confusion about whether `$LB_LIBRARY_PATH` as a command by itself should be valid or not.)

Comment: @EtanReisner it returns "declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64:" which indeed ends with a colon. I'm assuming from your comment that it shouldn't? what would be the possible fix?

Comment: No, a colon is fine there. But the colon **isn't** fine for `ls`, etc. so that's why it was complaining because `/usr/local/cuda/lib64:` **doesn't** exist. So we are left with what was the actual problem you were having that started this question? Was it just that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` run by itself at your prompt gave you the `-bash: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:: No such file or dictionary` error? Because that's the same reason (and executing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as a command isn't a reasonable thing to do in the first place. Was there some *actual* problem you were having here?

Comment: @EtanReisner I was installing caffe, and ran into library issue where it couldn't find the libcudart.so.6.0 (cuda btw has been updated to 7.5) so I thought there was a path issue..

Comment: @EtanReisner should I retest the ls commands, and if so, what should the command be?

Comment: No, there's nothing to do about the `ls` stuff. That's all working normally. The content of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't a single path so `ls` cannot use it. **What** error were you having with `caffe`? Does that file exist in the `/usr/local/cuda` directories anywhere? What does `find /usr/local/cuda -name '*.so*'` output?

Comment: @EtanReisner caffe was complaining specifically that it couldn't find libcuart.so.6.0. In /usr/local/cuda/lib and /usr/local/cuda/lib64 there are libcudart.so.7.5, yet find /usr/local/cuda - name '*.so*' returns nothing...

Comment: So you have a newer version of `cuda` than `caffe` supports. You need to get the version it expects to find (or find an updated version of `caffe` that supports the newer version of `cuda` that you have). You might need `find -H ...` or `find -L ...` for the `find` command to work because of the symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by modifying the Makefile.config as follows:

```
/usr/local/cuda
```

to

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5
```